# Running google cloud speech api on Android 4.2

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-speech

I have a problem running io.grpc:grpc-okhttp on Android 4.2 devices.

I have implemented SpeechClient with Credentials, for running Google cloud speech to text.
On Android 7.1 device I don't have a problem. The problems happen on Android 4.2

So in my starting gradle I had

```
implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.35.0'
implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-android:1.35.0'
implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-speech:1.24.0'
```

Problems.

1. First problem was with TLS security for SSL (which is too old on Android 4.2). For this, I added dependency

   ```
   implementation 'org.conscrypt:conscrypt-android:2.5.1'
   ```

   and implemented in my DialogFragment (which is running the code)

   ```
    Security.insertProviderAt(Conscrypt.newProvider(), 1)
   ```
2. After I implemented this, I am getting

   ```
   Duplicate class org.conscrypt.AbstractConscryptEngine found in modules jetified-conscrypt-android-2.5.1-runtime (org.conscrypt:conscrypt-android:2.5.1) and jetified-conscrypt-openjdk-uber-2.2.1 (org.conscrypt:conscrypt-openjdk-uber:2.2.1)
   ```

   issues (alot of duplicated classes)
   So for fixing this, I added

   ```
   configurations {
      all {
         exclude group: "org.conscrypt", module: "conscrypt-openjdk-uber"
      }
    }
   ```
3. Now I get this error, because com.google.api.client is using Standard.UTF-8 and my device is on Android 17.

```
com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnauthenticatedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAUTHENTICATED: Failed computing credential metadata
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:73)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ExceptionResponseObserver.onErrorImpl(ExceptionResponseObserver.java:82)
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.StateCheckingResponseObserver.onError(StateCheckingResponseObserver.java:86)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcDirectStreamController$ResponseObserverAdapter.onClose(GrpcDirectStreamController.java:149)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:426)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$500(ClientCallImpl.java:66)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:689)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$900(ClientCallImpl.java:577)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:751)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:740)
        at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
        at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:153)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:267)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
     Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAUTHENTICATED: Failed computing credential metadata
        at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcDirectStreamController$ResponseObserverAdapter.onClose(GrpcDirectStreamController.java:149) 
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:426) 
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$500(ClientCallImpl.java:66) 
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:689) 
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$900(ClientCallImpl.java:577) 
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:751) 
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:740) 
        at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) 
        at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123) 
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:153) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:267) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
        at com.google.api.client.util.StringUtils.getBytesUtf8(StringUtils.java:51)
        at com.google.api.client.json.webtoken.JsonWebSignature.signUsingRsaSha256(JsonWebSignature.java:571)
        at com.google.auth.oauth2.JwtCredentials.refresh(JwtCredentials.java:125)
        at com.google.auth.oauth2.JwtCredentials.getRequestMetadata(JwtCredentials.java:163)
        at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountJwtAccessCredentials.getRequestMetadata(ServiceAccountJwtAccessCredentials.java:365)
        at com.google.auth.Credentials.blockingGetToCallback(Credentials.java:112)
        at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountJwtAccessCredentials.getRequestMetadata(ServiceAccountJwtAccessCredentials.java:341)
        at io.grpc.auth.GoogleAuthLibraryCallCredentials.applyRequestMetadata(GoogleAuthLibraryCallCredentials.java:110)
        at io.grpc.CallCredentials2.applyRequestMetadata(CallCredentials2.java:58)
        at io.grpc.internal.CallCredentialsApplyingTransportFactory$CallCredentialsApplyingTransport.newStream(CallCredentialsApplyingTransportFactory.java:108)
        at io.grpc.internal.ForwardingConnectionClientTransport.newStream(ForwardingConnectionClientTransport.java:49)
        at io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel$CallTracingTransport.newStream(InternalSubchannel.java:671)
        at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientTransport$PendingStream.createRealStream(DelayedClientTransport.java:353)
        at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientTransport$PendingStream.access$300(DelayedClientTransport.java:341)
```

**Question:**

1. How to resolve this issue and run Speech with "ApiStreamObserver?
   I tried reverting back "io.grpc:grpc-" libraries to version 1.0 or something, but then I have other problems...

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue and commited example project on Github

https://github.com/DjToMeK27/CloudGoogleSpeechToText/tree/main

What I did in this project

1. Downloaded https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/blob/master/README.md
2. Changed classes in project SpeechRecognitionClient in android-docs-samples-master\speech

   - Changed AudioRecord in AudoEmitter.kt to support API 16
3. Imported org.conscrypt:conscrypt-android:2.5.1 library

   - Had to exclude group org.conscrypt from google-cloud-speech (in build.gradle)
4. Added init { Security.insertProviderAt(Conscrypt.newProvider(), 1) } For Android 4.1 to run proper TLS for GRC to work
5. I downloaded https://github.com/googleapis project

   - Changed all StandardCharsets found in google-http-client to Charset.forName())
   - And also changed some tests to work
   - https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5MAF.jpg (files changes)
6. I have build this project and added .jar files, which I included here
7. And now it works!